# Change emulator version android xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

I am new to xamarin development.

I am wondering, how can I change the emulator version to version 5.0 android api 21?

I have set my project to compile using android version 5.0 as per screenshot. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You will need to [create a new virtual device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/). You also need to ensure that you have the corresponding system image installed, which you can administrate from the [SDK Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/launch_sdk_manager/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Tools > Android > Android Emulator Manager.

Click on the AVD name of emulator you want to edit and click edit. You can select Android version by selecting Drop down "Target". You can change settings from there without creating new Emulator.